# OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: ‘/storage/data/oxford-iiit-pet/export.pkl’ (using fastai library)

Tags: python, deployment, deep-learning, dataset, fast-ai

I am working in a gradient notebook in Paperspace. I am using the PETS dataset in the fastai library to save and deploy the Classifying breeds. When I use the learn.export() command, I am getting the error OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: ‘/storage/data/oxford-iiit-pet/export.pkl’.

I read some of the problems of the same topics in the forum, but still, I have a problem.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I think the error is quite clear, the filesystem is read only, it is a local problem that you need to fix, so what is exactly the question?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the file system is read-only ?

Maybe you opened the file as read and not write. Would be my only guess other than that it is read-only